# Trap ESC key in a modal

Tags: lightning-web-components, modal

I want to override the behavior of the ESC key in my LWC while a modal is being displayed.  Default behavior passes the ESC key down to the calling component and closes both the modal and that component.  I can trap the ESC in the modal with this code:

```
    @track openModal = false;

    connectedCallback() { 
        this.template.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
            var keycode = event.code;
            console.log('keycode',keycode);
            if(keycode == 'Escape'){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        }, true);
    }

    showModal() {
        this.openModal = true;
    }
    closeModal() {
        this.openModal = false;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <!-- =============== Information Modal =============== -->
    <template if:true={openModal}>
        <div class="slds-modal slds-modal_small slds-fade-in-open slds-backdrop">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">

                <!-- Header Section -->
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                        alternative-text="Close this window" size="large" variant="bare-inverse"
                        onclick={closeModal} class="slds-modal__close">
                    </lightning-button-icon>
                    <h2 class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate slds-text-color_inverse">Information Screen for {bannerLabel}</h2>
                </div>

                <!-- Body Section -->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    <template for:each={bannerInfo} for:item="attribute">
                        <div key={attribute.label}>
                            <strong>{attribute.label}</strong>
                            <div>{attribute.helpText}</div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div>

                <!-- Footer Section -->
                <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                    <lightning-button label="Close Screen" variant="neutral"
                        icon-name="utility:close" 
                        onclick={closeModal}>
                    </lightning-button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Once I've trapped the ESC key, I want to close the modal.  I'm not sure how to make that happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the handler on the top-level element in your template, rather than dynamically:

```
<div onkeydown={handleKeyDown} class="slds-modal slds-modal_small slds-fade-in-open slds-backdrop">
```

Which should allow the escape key to be captured correctly:

```
handleKeyDown(event) {
  if(event.code == 'Escape') {
    this.openModal = false;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
}
```

Comment: The underlying component along with the modal still gets closed when trying your method.

Comment: Adding this.openModal = false; to the connectedCallback takes care of the issue.